# smart table +Angular js

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am using [Smart-table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#/section-intro) to show reports to the user with Angular js.

Now,I want to customize table header and want a colspan in smart table 's header.

Does anyone know about this?Is it possible?
Please share example,plunker if anyone have achieved this

Comment: Why don't you share with us an example plunkr, and we can help you achieve what you want...?

Comment: @Nix  
plnkr.co/edit/xsJs8m?p=preview Above plunkr is already created by some one.In above example I want one column called "NAME" which containts colspan=2 and in those cell First Name and Last Name will be stored

Answer (score 1):

You can have whatever template you want in cellTemplate attr, where I have concatenated both first name and last name.

Like I have used,

```
 scope.columnCollection = [
                { label: 'Name', map: 'FirstName', validationAttrs: 'required', validationMsgs: '<span class="error" ng-show="smartTableValidForm.FirstName.$error.required">Required!</span>',cellTemplate:'<div class="name"><span>{{dataRow.FirstName +" "+dataRow.LastName}}</span><div>'}, //have whatever template you want and your custom css
                //{ label: 'Last Name', map: 'LastName' },
                { label: 'User Name', map: 'UserName', validationAttrs: 'required' },
                { label: 'Password', map: 'Password', noList: true, editType: 'password' },
                { label: 'Customer', map: 'CustId', optionsUrl: '/GetCusts', editType: 'radio' },
                { label: 'Role', map: 'RoleId', optionsUrl: '/GetRoles', editType: 'select', defaultTemplate: '<option value="" ng-hide="dataRow[column.map]">---</option>', validationAttrs: 'required', validationMsgs: '<span class="error" ng-show="smartTableValidForm.RoleId.$error.required">Required!</span>' }, // NOTE: small hack which enables defaultTemplate option :)
                { label: 'E-mail', editType: 'email', map: 'Email' },
                { label: 'Cell Phone', map: 'Mobilephone', noEdit: true, validationAttrs: 'required' },
                { label: 'Locked', map: 'IsLocked', cellTemplate: '<input disabled type="checkbox" name="{{column.map}}" ng-model="dataRow[column.map]">', editType: 'checkbox', noAdd: true }
            ];
```

In css you can have your custom Css.

Please have a look at this 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qbDRoYZxqeVQIJx7Bd3I?p=preview)

Hope this solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation you need to add something like this:

```
app.controller('basicsCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
    scope.rowCollection = [
        {firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}
    ];

    scope.columnCollection = [
        {label: 'First Name', map: 'firstName'},
        {label: 'same same but different', map: 'firstName'},
        {label: 'Last Name', map: 'lastName'}
    ];
}]);
```

Your columnCollection will adjust the labels based on the mappings.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion.but not working. It will repeating the value because of  firstName mapping

Comment: Share some of your code so we know where you are starting

Comment: plnkr.co/edit/xsJs8m?p=preview Above plunkr is already created by someone.As per your suggestion I have tried and changed LastName to FirstName in columnCollection scope variable. but Output is like it's repeating firstName column's value to lastName column because we have same value "FirstName" in LastName columns map attribute